# Ajuda javascript | Renomear paragrafo

Tags: javascript, html

Ola gostaria de saber o seguinte, como eu faria a logica para renomear um paragrafo diretamente pelo html, Por exemplo.
Tenho um paragrafo vazio, o usuario clica no paragrafo e digita uma palavra da enter e a palavra seta o valor dela no paragrafo.
Um sistema de renomear.

Comment: Se eu entendi a sua pergunta, você poderia abrir um prompt para a pessoa digitar, e o que ela digitou você setaria em uma tag <p>. É isso? Se sim, precisaria usar o JavaScript para interceptar o click no parágrafo, abrir o prompt e depois atribuir o que foi digitado para a tag que foi clicada.

Comment: A sua lógica está esquisita, como assim clicar em um parágrafo vazio, se o parágrafo estiver vazio como o usuário saberá que tem um parágrafo ali??

Comment: `<p contentEditable = "true">teste</p> ` deve ser a forma mais rápida. Isso trona um elemento html editável.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenha em mente que as entradas do usuários são fornecidas pelo elemento `input`. Partindo desse princípio podemos seguir os passos abaixo:

1. Criar o elemento `input` quando o usuário clicar no parágrafo.
2. Obter o valor do `input` quando o usuário pressionar a tecla
   **enter**.
3. Inserir o valor obtido no parágrafo

```js
document.getElementById("editavel").addEventListener("click", editar);

function editar() {
  const paragraph = this;

  //Criando o input
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "input-text";
  input.type = "text";
  input.value = paragraph.innerText;

  //Substituindo o parágrafo pelo input recém criado
  paragraph.parentNode.replaceChild(input, paragraph);
  
  //Focando no elemento criado para melhorar experiência do usuário
  input.focus();
  
  //Identificando a tecla enter para salvar o texto digitado
  input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    const key = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) {
      saveText();
    }
  });
};

function saveText() {
  const input = document.getElementById("input-text");

  //Criando o novo parágrafo
  const newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
  newParagraph.id = "editavel";
  newParagraph.innerText = input.value;

  //Substituindo o input pelo parágrafo
  input.parentNode.replaceChild(newParagraph, input);

  //Adicionando o evento de click no novo elemento
  newParagraph.addEventListener("click", editar);
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

p {
  width: 70%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input {
  width: 70%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="editavel"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Incrivel, muito obrigado parceiro.

Comment: De nada, fico feliz em ajudá-lo! xD